# Error: Invalid CSS, while converting SASS to CSS

Tags: css, sass

I want to convert `styles.sass` file with a module named `_base.sass` to `styles.css` file.

**File structure:**

```
sass-files/
 - styles.sass
 - _base.sass

css-files/
```

**styles.sass**

```
@use 'base'

.inverse
  background-color: base.$primary-color
  color: white
```

**_base.sass**

```
$font-stack: Helvetica, sans-serif
$primary-color: #333

body
  font: 100% $font-stack
  color: $primary-color
```

**Commands**

```
sass styles.sass ../css-folder/styles.css
```

**Error**

```
Error: Invalid CSS after "base": expected expression (e.g. 1px, bold), was ".$primary-color"
        on line 4 of styles.sass
```

**System**

```
Linux Mint 19.1 (Tessa)
zsh 5.4.2 (x86_64-ubuntu-linux-gnu)
```

I don't understand the error and don't know what to do to solve the problem.

Comment: Are you using Dart Sass 1.23.0 or later?

Comment: It is Ruby Sass 3.7.4

Comment: "[Only Dart Sass currently supports `@use`. Users of other implementations must use the `@import` rule instead.](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/use)"

Comment: It didn't work as expected, ```@import``` gave the same error.
```@import base

.inverse
  background-color: base.$primary-color
  color: white```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dart-based `npm` package `dart-sass` worked. Ruby-based Sass does not support `@use` usage.

Comment: Related official documentation page: [Sass: @use](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/use).

Answer (score -1):

Just use `background-color: $primary-color` no need for `base.`

Comment: It gives ```Error: Undefined variable: "$primary-color". on line 4 of sass-files/styles.sass``` when I try what you suggest.

Comment: Apologies,  base.$primary-color is correct according to the docs. The docs also say Ruby Sass has reached end of life. Can you try using Dart Sass instead?

Comment: I tried and it worked. I used ```dart-sass``` npm package and it successfully compiled the CSS file.Thank you!